# ubuntu server 11.10 virus scanner

Tags: ubuntu

I currently had a site get listed as malware.
The website has nothing on it, They think it's a false alarm.

I'm running Ubuntu Linux 11.10 from ssh. I want to install a virus/maleware scanner from ssh.
What do you recommend that's free and easiest to install and run.

Thanks

Comment: *WHY* do you want a virus scanner? What purpose would this tool serve? Installing software without a clear idea of what it's going to do for you is not a good idea...

Comment: The _right_ thing to do is to find out _why_ your site is listed as having malware. Log into Google Webmaster Tools and it will tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ClamAv](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) is a pretty good virus scan, but I'm not sure your approaching your actual problem the right way.  Virus scanners for most *nix OS's are actually for other systems (not saying malware doesn't exist on the server itself).

`sudo apt-get install clamav`

You may want to consider a different aproach as to *why* you got listed as malware.  Many times it's a result of spoofing or you have open relay mail server sending spam to other networks.  Then again, this is just guess as result of the amount of detail given to the question.